# How to connect the SpringBoot JPA Entities in a POST request properly?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, orm, spring-data-jpa

I am creating an Library Management. I already created the relations between the entities and created the repositories. It's everything working, but it's working for the separated creation of the entity only. For example I want to send a POST request creating a Book, and creating the author and the theme. But I only can create the book, I want to know which is the best approach to achieve this. I don't know else if I should create service classes or use DTO I really don't know.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path ="/api/books")
public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    BookRepository bookRepository;

    @PostMapping
    public Book addBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
        bookRepository.save(book);
        return book;
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Book {

    public Book(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int isbn;

    @Column
    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<BookTheme> bookThemes = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

This is my book controller, and Entity (Model), the repository its simple I just extend the CRUD repository interface... anyway my doubt its I know how to create and save the object separated but I don't know how to merge them, how to make their relation work, like add two authors to one book in the Request body... I managed to save them in one only request but using params only and sometimes I create a loop because I save them both. I know its wrong but I don't know how to approach here.

```java
package com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Entities;
    
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Author {

    public Author(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Book> book = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

This is my `Author` entity:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path ="/api/author")
public class AuthorController {

    @Autowired
    AuthorRepository authorRepository;

    @PostMapping
    public Author addAuthor(@RequestParam String name){
        Author author = new Author(name);
        authorRepository.save(author);
        return author;
    }
}
```

And the author controller, the others entities are similar to this, I don't know what should I do, ive saw many, but older tutorials and I don't know if I should use that approach, and they don't seem to answer my question how to make the objects in the post request for example interact with their relations, like adding the book and the authors in the same request and save in the database.

Comment: Please i am trying to figure this for days unsucceeded!!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. When using entities with relations, DTOs will in most cases cause the least amount of trouble when serialzing/deserializing JSON. I will recommend you to start with a small proof-of-concept with e.g. a parent entity only.  Operations on your repositories should be moved from controllers to one or more service classes. BR

Comment: @RoarS. thank you my friend, i guess you are right, maybe i am trying to take a step higher than my leg (a Brazilian frase lol), i will try a simple ORM between two entites only and then i change to this and apply what ive learn, did you know any good source where i can learn this? Tutorial with explanation or a Book maybe? The only that i found dont use DTO's and some of them dont use even the service class either... Really appreciate my friend...

Comment: may be this helps https://mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

Comment: Hi Leonardo. A course will of course get you on track faster. I followed a course a few months ago when learning React with Spring Boot. I felt the Spring Boot-part (50%) was quite good and is relevant to what you are working with here. In addition, everything is done step-by-step. Of course there are other courses that will be more spot-on. 

https://www.udemy.com/course/test-driven-web-application-development-with-spring-react/

Course code here: https://github.com/basarbk/tdd-spring-react

Wish you good luck with your learning, and remember, never give up :-) BR

Comment: @SpringLearner Thank you my friend, but unfortanelly it doesn't, that way i learned how to do it, i want to know how to achieve theese results in REST requests you know? I've made an Hibernate Course and learned exactly like this!! But with requisitions if you want to send a Request Body in a JSON format for example it doesn"t work like this, but i really appreciate!!

Comment: @RoarS. thanks my friend i already made lots of udemy courses, just love it!! And this one explains about TDD i really need to improve in TDD and BDD...

Comment: @LeonardoTadeuMantovani what do you mean to achieve this in REST? Do you pass the all parent and child body in request body?Did you debug by checking if every elements are incoming to the controller?

Comment: @SpringLearner Yes it is working but i am not succeded when i add multiple objects, like i want to add a book, with two authors and two different themes for example, in the request for me its just possible to create the book object only (the title) and the authors i am not managing to do it, in the example that you sended i learned exactly like this using only hibernate and not SpringBoot also, for what i could read we have to create the repos and in the controller request and receive the object in the Request body

Comment: @SpringLearner if the tutorial that you sended could be fitted in this case what should be the approach? I've tried this way and wasn't succeded couldn't pass the object to the list and save, because it creates a infinite loop in the children. I really sorry if i seemed to be arrogant i really dont know if this way can be done!!

Comment: you are not able to send the authors and themes from the request? Where exactly you are stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make a proof-of-concept with many-to-many between `Book` and `Author` all the way, including integration tests. I leave it to you to complete the `BookTheme` part.

Please note that I simplified your code a little bit, and I changed your collections from `List` to `Set` (the latter is about persisting collections).

Author entity

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.book;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors")
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();

    public Author(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

AuthorVM (DTO)

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.book;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AuthorVM {

    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    public AuthorVM(Author author) {
        this.id = author.getId();
        this.name = author.getName();
    }
}
```

Book entity

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.book;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long isbn;

    private String title;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();

    public void addAuthor(Author author) {
        authors.add(author);
    }
}
```

BookVM (DTO). Please note the use of `List<@Valid AuthorVM>`. This is for enabling validation of each `AuthorVM` instance.

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.book;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BookVM {
    private long isbn;

    @NotNull
    private String title;

    @Size(min = 1)
    private List<@Valid AuthorVM> authors = new ArrayList<>();

    public BookVM(Book book) {
        this.isbn = book.getIsbn();
        this.title = book.getTitle();
        this.authors = book.getAuthors().stream()
                .map(AuthorVM::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

BookRepo

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.book;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface BookRepo extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {
}
```

AuthorRepo

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.book;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface AuthorRepo extends JpaRepository<Author, Long> {
}
```

BookService

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.book;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BookService {

    private final BookRepo bookRepo;
    private final AuthorRepo authorRepo;

    public Book saveBook(BookVM bookVM) {

        // create new  book instance
        var book = new Book();
        book.setTitle(bookVM.getTitle());

        // fetch existing authors from db, save new authors to db, attach author to book
        bookVM.getAuthors().forEach(authorVM -> book.addAuthor(
                authorVM.getId() > 0
                        ? authorRepo.getOne(authorVM.getId())
                        : authorRepo.save(new Author(authorVM.getName()))));

        // save book and return saved instance
        return bookRepo.save(book);
    }
}
```

And finally, the controller

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.book;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path ="/api/books")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BookController {

    private final BookService bookService;

    @PostMapping
    public BookVM addBook(@Valid @RequestBody BookVM book){
        return new BookVM(bookService.saveBook(book));
    }
}
```

And some integration tests that verifies that things are working.

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.book;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.AutoConfigureWebTestClient;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
class BookControllerTest {

    static final String API_BOOKS = "/api/books";

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired
    private BookRepo bookRepo;

    @Autowired
    private AuthorRepo authorRepo;

    @BeforeEach
    public void cleanupDb() {
        bookRepo.deleteAll();
        authorRepo.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void postBook_bookNotValid_receiveBadRequest() {
        var book = createValidBook();
        book.setTitle(null);

        webTestClient.post().uri(API_BOOKS)
                .bodyValue(book)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isBadRequest();
    }

    @Test
    public void postBook_bookWitNoAuthors_receiveBadRequest() {
        var book = createValidBook();
        book.getAuthors().clear();

        webTestClient.post().uri(API_BOOKS)
                .bodyValue(book)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isBadRequest();
    }

    @Test
    public void postBook_bookWithInvalidAuthor_receiveBadRequest() {
        var book = createValidBook();
        book.getAuthors().get(0).setName(null);

        webTestClient.post().uri(API_BOOKS)
                .bodyValue(book)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isBadRequest();
    }

    @Test
    public void postBook_validBook_receiveOk() {
        webTestClient.post().uri(API_BOOKS)
                .bodyValue(createValidBook())
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();
    }

    @Test
    public void postBook_validBook_receiveCreatedBookWithCreatedAuthor() {
        var book = createValidBook();

        webTestClient.post().uri(API_BOOKS)
                .bodyValue(book)
                .exchange()
                .expectBody(BookVM.class)
                .value(bookVM -> {
                    assertThat(bookVM.getIsbn()).isGreaterThan(0);

                    var bookInDb = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().find(Book.class, bookVM.getIsbn());
                    assertThat(bookInDb.getAuthors().size()).isEqualTo(1);
                    assertThat(bookInDb.getTitle()).isEqualTo(book.getTitle());

                    var authorInDb = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().find(Author.class, bookVM.getAuthors().get(0).getId());
                    assertThat(authorInDb.getBooks().size()).isEqualTo(1);
                    assertThat(authorInDb.getName()).isEqualTo(book.getAuthors().get(0).getName());
                });

    }

    private BookVM createValidBook() {
        var book = new BookVM();
        book.setTitle("book-title");

        var author = new AuthorVM();
        author.setName("author-name");

        book.getAuthors().add(author);
        return book;
    }
}
```

Please add this to your POM if not already using `WebTestClient` in your project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Tests are working with

```
spring:
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
```

Comment: My friend, i really, really don't know how to thank you!!!

Comment: And about the code changes for simplify i appreciate a lot, when someone much more expert than i show me how to do it, i can learn from it, and that is the most important part for me, i really make a point in how the things are develop instead of just copy the code, so i will take this opportunity to learn with someone better than me, thanks my friend!!!!

Comment: @LeonardoTadeuMantovani: Pleasure is all mine :-) Hope you can use this code as a starting point. Many applications are using this kind of approach. Wish you a productive, pleasent weekend. BR